# Change child CSS on parent:hover

Tags: html, css, styles

I am trying to change a child elements CSS by hovering over the parent. Below is an example of my markup:

```
<ul class="effect">
  <li> something here </li>
</ul>
```

When you hover over the UL, this transition happens:

```
.effect:hover{ 
transform: translate(0,-5px);
-webkit-transform: translate(0,-5px);
-o-transform: translate(0,-5px); 
-moz-transform: translate(0,-5px); 
}
```

My UL element is dark grey, while the LI is styled with white and blue text. I want to make it so the UL turns blue, and the blue text in my LI turns white.

You can see what I am trying to accomplish in my tabs, under the slider, [here](http://www.elevancement.com/)

Comment: It's pretty straightforward: `.effect:hover > li { ... }`

Comment: My apologies, had to step away from the computer for a while. Believe it or not I have never used the > before in CSS, and I have been doing this a long time. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually *need* the `>`, I just used it for "more correctness".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
.effect:hover > li { color: red; }
```

So when you hover the `.effect` elements, the li childs, which are directly under the element will be affected.

```
<ul class="effect">
  <li> <!-- affected -->
    <ul>
      <li></li> <!-- not affected! -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is useful for dynamic CSS navigations, because not all the children are affected from the hover..

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I have never used the ">" before in CSS. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.effect:hover .effect li
{
    color: #0000ff /* blue color */
}

.effect:hover
{    
    color: #fff /* white color */
}
```